# Sidekiq mechanize overwritten instance

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize, sidekiq

I am building a simple web spider using Sidekiq and Mechanize.

When I run this for one domain, it works fine. When I run it for multiple domains, it fails. I believe the reason is that `web_page` gets overwritten when instantiated by another Sidekiq worker, but I am not sure if that's true or how to fix it.

```
# my scrape_search controller's create action searches on google.
def create
  @scrape = ScrapeSearch.build(keywords: params[:keywords], profession: params[:profession])
  agent = Mechanize.new
  scrape_search = agent.get('http://google.com/') do |page|
    search_result = page.form...
    search_result.css("h3.r").map do |link|
      result = link.at_css('a')['href'] # Narrowing down to real search results
      @domain = Domain.new(some params)
      ScrapeDomainWorker.perform_async(@domain.url, @domain.id, remaining_keywords)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm creating a Sidekiq job per domain. Most of the domains I'm looking for should contain just a few pages, so there's no need for sub-jobs per page.

This is my worker:

```
class ScrapeDomainWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  ...

  def perform(domain_url, domain_id, keywords)
    @domain       = Domain.find(domain_id)
    @domain_link  = @domain.protocol + '://' + domain_url
    @keywords     = keywords

    # First we scrape the homepage and get the first links
    @domain.to_parse = ['/']  # to_parse is an array of PATHS to parse for the domain
    mechanize_path('/')
    @domain.verified << '/' # verified is an Array field containing valid domain paths
    get_paths(@web_page) # Now we should have to_scrape populated with homepage links 

    @domain.scraped = 1 # Loop counter
    while @domain.scraped < 100
      @domain.to_parse.each do |path|
        @domain.to_parse.delete(path)
        @domain.scraped += 1
        mechanize_path(path) # We create a Nokogiri HTML doc with mechanize for the valid path
        ...
        get_paths(@web_page) # Fire this to repopulate to_scrape !!!
      end
    end
    @domain.save
  end

  def mechanize_path(path)
    agent = Mechanize.new
    begin
      @web_page = agent.get(@domain_link + path)
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Mechanize Exception for #{path} :: #{e.message}"
    end
  end

  def get_paths(web_page)
    paths = web_page.links.map {|link| link.href.gsub((@domain.protocol + '://' + @domain.url), "") } ## This works when I scrape a single domain, but fails with ".gsub for nil" when I scrape a few domains.
    paths.uniq.each do |path|
      @domain.to_parse << path
    end  
  end

end
```

This works when I scrape a single domain, but fails with `.gsub for nil` for `web_page` when I scrape a few domains.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Please reduce the code to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap you code in another class, and then create and object of that class within your worker:

```
class ScrapeDomainWrapper
  def initialize(domain_url, domain_id, keywords)
    # ...
  end

  def mechanize_path(path)
    # ...
  end

  def get_paths(web_page)
    # ...
  end
end
```

And your worker:

```
class ScrapeDomainWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(domain_url, domain_id, keywords)
    ScrapeDomainWrapper.new(domain_url, domain_id, keywords)
  end
end
```

Also, bear in mind that `Mechanize::Page#links` may be a `nil`.

Comment: I wrapped it as you suggested. I also converted all instance variables to local variables (@web_page became web_page, etc.). I still get a "undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass" for paths = web_page.links.map {|link| link.href.gsub((@domain.protocol + '://' + @domain.url), "") }. Strangely enough, if I run it solo, it works just fine.

Comment: If you moved the code to another class, then you don't need to rename your variables. As long as they are not class variables, but instance variables, everything is ok. Also, I think that `Mechanize::Link#href` may be `nil` in some cases. You should check for that.

Comment: Yeah, I added a failsafe for that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's no class variables in his code sample.  Instance variables are perfectly safe to use in Sidekiq jobs.

Comment: @MikePerham You're right, I was thinking about Resque's behaviour.